# SQLite select statement optimisation advice

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table 'Details' with structure:

```
ID  Name    Category   
---------------------
1   Matt    0 
2   Shervin 0 
3   Bob     0   
4   Lee     0 
5   Rick    0   
6   Suraya  0 
7   Susan   0   
8   Adam    0   
9   Jon     1   
10  Lorna   1 
... and so on .......
```

I want to select a row at random, and then three names from three different rows (again preferably at random).  I would like this to all be returned from one SQLite statement.  E.g.

```
ID  Name  Category  Name1  Name2  Name 3  
----------------------------------------
3   Bob   0         Matt   Lee    Susan
```

My attempt at this can be seen below, but it has two problems:

1. The three extra names are not necessarily always different - I can't seem to exclude a name that has been previously selected because variables b/c/d are not in scope apart from their own COALESCE function.
2. As each nested select uses the Random() function it’s not very efficient.

Can anyone suggest another way to select the data I need (using SQLite database)?  Any help/advice is welcome - hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve, feel free to ask for any clarifications.

My current attempt:

```
SELECT a.Id,
       a.Name,
       a.Category,
       COALESCE((SELECT b.Name 
                   FROM Details b 
                  WHERE b.Id NOT IN (a.Id)
                    AND b.Category IN (0)
               ORDER BY Random()
                  LIMIT 1),'') as "Name1",
       COALESCE((SELECT c.Name 
                   FROM Details c 
                  WHERE c.Id NOT IN (a.Id)
                    AND c.Category IN (0)
               ORDER BY Random()
                  LIMIT 1),'') as "Name2",
       COALESCE((SELECT d.Name 
                   FROM Details d
                  WHERE d.Id NOT IN (a.Id)
                    AND d.Category IN (0)
               ORDER BY Random()
                  LIMIT 1),'') as "Name3"
    FROM Details a
     AND a.Category IN (0)
ORDER BY Random()
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I can't see any advantage in doing this _shuffle_ in sql rather than in the code that will handle that data (if any of course)

Comment: @neurino: Some advantage might be in that if you do that in SQL, you'll get to transfer less data to the client than if you choose to pick the items on the client side from the entire list.

Comment: @neurino: I'm using this code in a iPhone app.  So my thought process was to try and keep to a minimum both the amount of data that was transferred and the number of calls made to the SQLite db.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, thanks for the edit - learnt how to format the tables on SO now.

Comment: @Andiry: and on which order of millions of _usernames_ (I considered this too) you can reasonably gain in performance?

Comment: @MattStacey: I'm not a SQL guru but it seems to me you are asking SQLite a duty (multiple cominations i.e. with no repetitions) that does not argue it. Moreover if you don't even need to rely on bandwith speed limitations in data transfer.

Comment: @neurino: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. SQLite might turn out more prepared to dealing with millions of records than the client application, if that's what you were asking about.

Comment: @Andiry: I was told to always profile before so until the OP doesn't do it we cannot know. BTW I told _millions of usernames_ just because in OP case they could be a few thousands, or hundreds, he didn't say, are you sure he wants to store all Facebook's usernames on an iPhone? ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm with neurino here. You have not said why you need to put the four names chosen at random into a single row, and why this has to be done in the back-end.

If you're concerned about performance, generate random integers in your client (range >= min(pkcol) and <= max(pkcol) ) until you've found four distinct rows (i.e. entities/names). There's a chance that no row exists with one of the generated ids, but that takes mere milliseconds to find out.  Taking that random-key approach you could avoid an order by. The approach would work quickly even for tables with billions of rows.

P.S. (After finding out it was an iPhone app)
You need one call to get the min and max ID values (it's the PK so that uses an index).  Then you need at least another call to the DB (again, index-assisted) to get the four distinct rows using your randomly generated PK values [where ID in (a, b, c , d) ]  The maximum number of calls is unknown; how many will depend on the density of your primary key sequence.  I do not believe this would be an inordinate amount of I/O and it would be considerably less resource-intensive than an order by Random()--especially if the table has many rows.  You could always generate an ID list of 8, 12, 16 ids at random and have your client cull only the 4 rows required if more than 4 are returned.

P.P.S. Typically it is the instantiation of the database connection that is expensive, and you don't want to do that in a loop or any more often than you need to. But you can open a connection, run two or three efficient selects that return a few rows each, and then close if you're done with the task at hand.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am using the SQLite statement in an iPhone app and was of the thought process (perhaps incorrectly???) to try and minimise the data transferred between the db and iPhone app.  Your idea is an interesting approach but I think I have read somewhere that apple guidelines is to minimise calls to the db as much as possible - in hindsight I should have probably mentioned this was for an iPhone app in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments Tim they have been a big help and enabled me to look at this problem from another perspective.  Think my final solution will be derived from a combination of both yours and Andriy's comments

Comment: after some more thought I have decided to go with your suggestions.  I have split my statement into two separate calls to the database, the second returning three rows (using order by Random and limit 3) containing only the Name column.  Performance is a lot better now.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-statement solution, which uses a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE names
AS
SELECT
  Id,
  Name,
  Category
FROM Details
WHERE Category IN (0)
ORDER BY Random()
LIMIT 4;

SELECT
  MAX(CASE rowid WHEN 1 THEN Id END) AS Id,
  MAX(CASE rowid WHEN 1 THEN Name END) AS Name,
  MAX(CASE rowid WHEN 1 THEN Category END) AS Id,
  MAX(CASE rowid WHEN 2 THEN Name END) AS Name1,
  MAX(CASE rowid WHEN 3 THEN Name END) AS Name2,
  MAX(CASE rowid WHEN 4 THEN Name END) AS Name3
FROM names;

DROP TABLE names;
```

Comment: Thanks Andriy, looks like it might be along the lines of exactly what I need.  When I get a chance (probably the weekend - busy week at the office) I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a full outer join x3, then simply choosing a row at random where the names are not equal?

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve what you want by nesting the queries to have the names as a returned value. You essentially get the fourth value first and then the third and so on. All the while ensuring that they don't match. I should have passed through the Id field and checked that the Id's don't conflict rather than the names, but this way means unique names.

```
 SELECT Id
      ,Name
      ,Category
      ,bName
      ,cName
      ,dName 
FROM Details,
    (
        SELECT Name AS bName, cName, dName 
        FROM Details,
            (
                SELECT Name AS cName, dName 
                FROM Details,
                    (
                        SELECT Name AS dName 
                        FROM Details 
                        WHERE Category IN (0) 
                        ORDER BY Random() 
                        LIMIT 1
                    ) td
                WHERE Name <> dName 
                AND Category IN (0) 
                ORDER BY Random() 
                LIMIT 1
            ) tc 
        WHERE Name <> dName 
        AND Name <> cName 
        AND Category IN (0) 
        ORDER BY Random() 
        LIMIT 1
    ) tb
WHERE Name <> dName 
AND Name <> cName 
AND Name <> bName 
AND Category IN (0) 
ORDER BY Random() 
LIMIT 1;
```

I don't see a way around the Random() function and the slowness it generates other than generating the random Id's in code, but that has other problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main methods to optimize an order by random() statement.

The first is to remove the sorting of the whole table step altogether, but it doesn't work on all platforms: `limit 1 offset random()`, rather than `order by random() limit 1`.

The other works on all platforms but requires that your primary keys be reasonably dense (an auto-incrementing integer with no little if any deletes ensures they are). Pre-fetch a smaller set of IDs starting at a random starting point, and to use them in a subquery:

```
select *
from (select *
      from tbl
      where id between :x and :x + 20
      )
order by random()
limit 1
```